# How to get total WordPress post count on a parent category including the post of it's child

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

My plan is to get only first level categories to show up with total post count not only it's but including it's child categories.

I have come up with several question and answer regarding this but none of them is actually meeting the solution. As example, here below is one solution showing wrong result while a post is in multiple subcategory or both parent category and child category is selected

```
function wp_get_cat_postcount($id) {
    $cat = get_category($id);
    $count = (int) $cat->count;
    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $id,
    );
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $count +=$tax_term->count;
    }

    return $count;
}
```

### Edit: Show the use

I am actually querying all parent category and then trying to use this function to get post count for each parent category. Here is the use of the function above.

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'orderby'       => 'count',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
);

$cats = get_categories($args);

if ( is_array($cats) && !empty($cats) ) {

    echo '<ul class="cat-nav" id="cat-nav">';

    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        if($cat_type->count > 0){
            echo '<li>' . $cat->name . '<span class="post-count">'.wp_get_cat_postcount($cat->term_id).'</span></a></li>';
        }
    }

    echo '</ul>';

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more background? How are you using this function? What is $id? A taxonomy ID, post ID? or what?

Comment: It's the term-_id from each 1st level category. I have updated with edit